# How to view path of executed file?

Tags: unix

When I execute a command such as mycommand.ksh how can I find where that command is being executed from ? Something like "runCommandWithFullPathDisplayed mycommand.ksh"

I've tried finding the commands using "echo $path" but do not see the dir where the command is located.

Comment: `which  mycommand.ksh` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to find the location of the binary being executed using:

```
which command
```

For instance:

```
$ which ls
/bin/ls
```